# What instead of SURF in logo (visual sample) finding?

Tags: image-processing, computer-vision, artificial-intelligence

I have a task to find logo image within photographic picture. I need to locate logo and calculate it's perspective distortion (logos are on plastic cards).

Classic way from textbooks is to use SURF. Unfortunately, SURF has several disadvantages here:

1) logo image has relatively few features and it is hard to find it within big picture (actually effectiveness appeared to be very low)

2) logo image has very significant coloring, which SURF does not use

My questions are:

1) what is the correct name of the task of finding small distorted image inside big picture?

2) are there any methods for this task, other than SURF features matching?

For example, I can imagine many samples of distorted logo image, digitized with different resolutions. I think if I will start finding at low resolution, I could filter out bad hypotheses early. Going gradually to higher resolutions, I could simultaneously match image and determine it's projection parameters.

Are the some methods resembling this approach?

Answer (score 3):

have you tried the [MSER algorithm](http://cmp.felk.cvut.cz/~matas/papers/matas-bmvc02.pdf)? It always worked great for me.

---End of the standard answer, proceed only if you have time and enjoy playing with image processing---

Also in searching for a template with a relatively small area I developed an approach to use the template's stable extremal regions (SER) to map the scanning area for another, more powerful/resource-intensive algorithm. This approach is extremely easy to implement and worked wonders in my last project. If you are interested, the implementation would be as follows (MatLab code, but no fancy functions or vectorization):

Try to identify the unique stability interval (MinT-MaxT) of your logo with a program like this:

```
TestImage=imread('Leaves.jpg');

TestImage=rgb2gray(TestImage); %Transform RGB to grayscale

NewSER=zeros(size(TestImage)); %initialise stuff
OldSER=zeros(size(TestImage));
SpinSER=zeros(size(TestImage));

Hot=zeros(size(TestImage)); %your stability map

MaxT=255; %your interval, unlike MSER you don't use the whole bit-depth
MinT=1; %try something like 40-150 if you have high contrast in your logo 

for k=MaxT:-1:MinT

    TestImage1=im2bw(TestImage,k/256);

    imshow(abs(Hot/Interval))
    colormap(hot)

    hold on

    text(20,30,['Treshold: ',num2str(k)],'Color','k','FontWeight','bold','FontSize',16,'BackgroundColor','r')

    hold off

    OldSER=NewSER;
    NewSER=TestImage1;

    for i=1:size(TestImage,1);
        for j=1:size(TestImage,2)

            if OldSER(i,j)==NewSER(i,j) && SpinSER(i,j)==0 % Do the extremal regions remain the same/ are they stable over both thresholds?

                Hot(i,j)=Hot(i,j)+1;

            else

                Hot(i,j)=Hot(i,j)-1;

                SpinSER(i,j)=1;

            end

        end

    end

    shg

    pause(0.1)

end
```

Once you identified what interval works for your region generate a map to discriminate the rest of the image, and search the map for regions of interest.

```
MaxT=120;

MinT=40;

Map=zeros(x,y);                    %Create a map for the SER-filtering


% TestImageMinT=im2bw(Image,MinT/256);   %Set the range of the extremal region stability.
% TestImageMaxT=im2bw(Image,MaxT/256);
% 
% for i=1:x
%     for j=1:y
%         
%         Map(i,j)=TestImageMaxT(i,j)==TestImageMinT(i,j) ; %Map the pixels that remain stable over the interval
% 
%     end
% end

 Map=abs(Image-(MaxT-MinT)/(2*MaxT))*2*MaxT/(MaxT-MinT); %More or less equivalent to the loop comented above but >10x faster...
 Map=Map>0.5; %...
```

And apply whatever detector you want to that area or to ¬(that area)

```
Corners = CornerSusanMapped(ImageBW,Map,17);
```

Hope that helps and have fun!

Comment: Sorry didn't understand. How do you compare MSER feature vectors?

Comment: It is not really the feature vectors. The thing is much more simple than that. As you transform a grayscale image to BW, if you start with a threshold of 0 and go all the way to 1 (or 0 to 255), you will start with a completely black image and, as more and more objects become white, you will en up with a completely white image.  What I do then is, scan only the pixels that maintain the same value over a threshold interval.

Comment: If your logo is near to white, you can scan only the pixels that maintain the same value for the threshold 10 to 255. If there's also a black portion you can add the pixels that remain stable from, say, 0 to 200. If you are looking for a gray, you can take all the pixels that do not remain stable when passing thresholded with 128... and so on and so on. Once you mapped the areas you want to scan you can scan that with another algorithm. in my case this was a corner detector that would have otherwise scanned hundreds of corners all around the image. If you upload your logo I'll give it a look.